# How to automatically populate the values of a column into a new data frame?

Tags: r, data-transform, writexl

This is a kind of problem of problem that is generally solved using Microsoft Excel. Since I am not familiarized with VBA and Macros I need to take the help of `R`.

The data frame looks like this.

```
df <- data.frame(player_no = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), player = c("Ram", "Shyam", "Jordan", "Chris", "Salim", "Salman"), sold_to = c("Team_1", "Team_2", "Team_3", "Team_2", "Team_3", "Team_1"))
```

Now I wish to create a new data frame wherein the values of the player_no and the player gets automatically populated into the respective teams.

The pictorial representation of what is expected is shown below:-

[image]

The expected output is as follows

```
#          Team 1                    Team 2              Team 3
# Sno player_no  player  Sno  player_no  player  Sno player_no player
# 1    1          Ram     1     2         Shyam   1   3         Jordan
# 2    6          Salman  2     4         Chris   2   5         Salim
```

Once the expected output is achieved, is it possible to transfer back the output into an excel file (using `writexl` package) that mimics the pictorial representation that is mentioned in the question ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="sold_to", 
              names_glue="{sold_to}_{.value}", 
              values_from=c("player_no", "player"), 
              values_fn=list
              ) %>%
  unnest(everything()) %>%
  select(Team_1_player_no, Team_1_player, 
         Team_2_player_no, Team_2_player, 
         Team_3_player_no, Team_3_player)
```

which returns not exactly your desired output, but it's quite similar:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Team_1_player_no Team_1_player Team_2_player_no Team_2_player Team_3_player_no Team_3_player
             <dbl> <fct>                    <dbl> <fct>                    <dbl> <fct>        
1                1 Ram                          2 Shyam                        3 Jordan       
2                6 Salman                       4 Chris                        5 Salim
```